# creating event on every sunday using cron job php

Tags: php, cron, cron-task

i want to create events on every sunday to user.

this is the description:

Event creation is automatically happens from system. System automatically choose random members, location and create an event.System automatically create the event on Sunday before end of the day. The users must accept or reject their event on or before Monday end of the day. The event happens on all Thursday as default time.

can anybody give me any idea about this task, using php. i am a php beginner . please anybody help.

i searched in google , got some information they tells that use a cron job , this is the link : https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/scheduling-tasks-with-cron-jobs--net-8800 but i din't get anything.

Answer (score 1):

To run a php script on a Sunday at 4pm, you can use the following cron entry:

```
0 16 * * 0 /path/to/php create-event.php
```

To run a script on a Monday at 5pm:

```
0 17 * * 1 /path/to/php deadline.php
```

To get /path/to/php on a Linux system, type `which php`.

However, helping you with the content of each script is outside the scope of a single answer.

Comment: i didn't get . can you give more details .. create-event.php is for php code for creating event , right ? can i use this cronjob in localhost ?

Comment: Yes, that's the idea. You'd have one script to create the event and one to perform the tasks after the deadline on Monday. The task needs to run as a cron job of whatever host holds your php scripts.